# Weighted Quick Union Tree Height

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble understanding the tree height portion. The height cannot be greater than lg N, where N is the number of items.

lg 10 = 1

Therefore, a set of 10 items cannot have a height greater than 1. But I am able quick union values 0-9 (the ten items) and have heights up to 3.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I guess log is to the base 2

Comment: Splendid! Everything makes more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logarithm, as a function has two parameters, the first being the base and the second the number. So:

```
logarithm(base, number) = power
```

means that if you take the base as `base` and raise it to the power of `power`, then your result will be the `number`. logarithm answers you the question:

> which power should I raise the base to to get the number as a result.

If all your nodes have n children, then your branches have an exponentiality of the base n, so k nodes would need a height of no less than `log(n, k)`. Or you can define the height in your own way as well.

If you have a binary tree, then n = 2.

Comment: I do believe a quick-union tree is log base 2, but it's not a binary tree. A node can, in fact, have any number of children.

Comment: I am sorry, I believe I have missed the part where you have defined the concept of quick-union tree or pointed us to the right direction.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure. Well, I don't believe it's actually called a "quick-union tree", but that's what OP called it.